# Macro stepper in DrRacket

Tags: macros, scheme, racket, expansion

On the link http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/ryanc/macro-stepper/tutorial.html there are instructions for working with the macro stepper.

However, when I'm going to try it, I can't get the second expansion of myor in the definition of nonzero? function, only the first. Also, I have no buttons "Previous term" and "Next term".

So my question is: how i must configure macro stepper to get the second expansion, like in tutorial?

Comment: You might want to try the #racket freenode irc channel. This sort of question would benefit from a back-and-forth conversation which StackOverflow doesn't really provide.

Comment: Yeah Dan, I know that. But, unfortunately I cannot ask my questions there because I'm banned from Racket users group (Shriram Krishnamurthi hates me because I criticized their web framework).

Comment: @Greg H: yes, I'm very grateful to dyoo and I expressed that by upvoting his answer. I don't know how to mark his answer as accepted (could not find that button)

Comment: Near the upvote/downvote buttons, do you see the outline of a check mark? If you click that, it will turn solid green and you have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that your source program looked something like this:

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax myor
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(myor e) e]
    [(myor e1 . es)
     (let ([r e1]) (if r r (myor . es)))]))
(define (nonzero? r)
  (myor (negative? r)
        (positive? r)))
```

Short story: use **syntax-case** rather than **syntax-rules** for the moment; there appears to be some bug associated with the Macro stepper and syntax-rules.  I've sent along a [bug report](http://bugs.racket-lang.org/query/?cmd=view&pr=12508) to the Racket developers, so hopefully this will be fixed soon.  The **syntax-case** version of the above program looks like this.

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (myor stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ e) #'e]
    [(_ e1 . es)
     #'(let ([r e1]) (if r r (myor . es)))]))

(define (nonzero? r)
  (myor (negative? r)
        (positive? r)))
```

---

Below is the longer story...

When I run your program under the pre-release of 5.2.1, I see the following in the Macro Stepper, with Macro hiding set to "Standard":

```
(module anonymous-module racket
  (#%module-begin
   (define-syntax myor
     (syntax-rules () [(myor e) e] [(myor e1 . es) (let ([r e1]) (if r r (myor . es)))]))
   (define (nonzero? r)
     (let:26 ([r:26 (negative? r)]) (if:26 r:26 r:26 (myor:26 (positive? r)))))))
```

which looks wrong.  It expands only one use of **myor** out to uses of **if**.  Very odd!

Let's see what things look like under Racket 5.2...

```
(module anonymous-module racket
  (#%module-begin
   (define-syntax myor
     (syntax-rules () [(myor e) e] [(myor e1 . es) (let ([r e1]) (if r r (myor . es)))]))
   (define (nonzero? r) (let ([r (negative? r)]) (if r r (myor (positive? r)))))))
```

Ah.  Ok, I can confirm that I see the same problem that you see in Racket 5.2, as well as the pre-release.

The bug seems related to the behavior of the "Macro hiding" feature, which tries to not overwhelm you with the full expansion when it is set to Standard.  If you set it to "Disabled", you'll see that the macro debugger will show the expansion in its full, unvarnished glory, and it does include the expansion that we expect to see:

```
(module anonymous-module racket
  (#%module-begin
   (define-syntaxes (myor)
     (lambda (x)
        ; ... I'm omitting the content here: it's way too long.
     ))
   (define-values:20 (nonzero?)
     (lambda:21 (r) (let-values:22 (((r) (#%app:23 negative? r))) (if r r (#%app:24 positive? r)))))))
```

I'll write a [bug report](http://bugs.racket-lang.org/query/?cmd=view&pr=12508) and send it to the Racket developers.

If you write your macro using **syntax-case**, as opposed to **syntax-rules**, it appears to work better with the Macro Stepper.

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (myor stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ e) #'e]
    [(_ e1 . es)
     #'(let ([r e1]) (if r r (myor . es)))]))

(define (nonzero? r)
  (myor (negative? r)
        (positive? r)))
```

When I step through this, it appears to work a lot better.  So whatever is triggering the bug, it appears to be some interaction with the Macro Stepper and **syntax-rules**.  So try using **syntax-case** instead.

Comment: Cool.  If the answer is acceptable, mark this question as answered so that it's off the "unanswered" list on SO.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me without having to do anything additional. Try with the newest version of Racket, also try choosing a different language from the menu, and make sure that `debugging` is selected for the language you select.

Comment: I'm running DrRacket 5.2 on Windows 7, language is #lang racket Here's screenshot: http://www.uploadscreenshot.com/image/705182/3970725

Comment: @RacketNoob: Looks like you are trying to step thru a module expansion and not a macro expansion.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the second expansion of myor (button "Step ->" after first click is grayed whatever I do). Can someone give detailed step-by-step instructions how to get all macro expansion steps to the end?