# why my macro-stepper not have "Next term"?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

may be redundance with : [Macro stepper in DrRacket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961762/macro-stepper-in-drracket)

but my question here is "why  I have no buttons "Previous term" and "Next term".in my macro-stepper?
I notice there: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/ryanc/macro-stepper/macro-stepper-Z-H-1.html#node_chap_1
say:

> When your program consists of multiple top-level definitions or expressions, the macro stepper also provides “Previous term” and “Next term” buttons to go up and down in the terms of your program.

in my opinion,top-level mean "in a module",but what the "multiple top-level definitions" means?can someone give me a example to explanations it?
I have try write two define-rule macro in different and export them ,and have seen the two macro in macro-steper occur ,but there still not the "next term".

is there have any more articles on how to use it?
Is it because that article is out of date and there is no "previous term" and "next term" button in the current dracket?

DrRacket version: 7.6 in windows10

I find this :

https://github.com/racket/macro-debugger/blob/13ee731da98fbe14a0d486d614a5c46f26ccd933/macro-debugger/macro-debugger/macro-debugger.scrbl#L258

https://github.com/racket/macro-debugger/blob/master/macro-debugger/macro-debugger/view/stepper.rkt#L84

but I still not know what "multiple top-level definitions"means..

I have try create two file ,and the source like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTwr4.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JmPW.jpg

and when I begin macro-stepper,it show like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mYrB.jpg
there only have four button,not the"previous term" and "next term".
or I misunderstanding the "multiple top-level definitions"?

update:I find this:

> If the macro stepper is showing multiple expansions, then it also provides “Previous term”
>   and “Next term” buttons to go up and down in the list of expansions. Horizontal lines delimit
>   the current expansion from the others.

Comment: Screenshot? Please.

Comment: Show a screenshot where the buttons are missing.

Comment: @soegaard:can you show me a example about "multiple top-level definitions",thanks!

Comment: @soegaard:sorry ,it seem I can't upload two picture on the question

Comment: Upload it to imgur and paste the link.

Comment: @soegaard : I have upload it.

Comment: The four buttons shown at the top are “go to start”, “prev term”, “next term” and “go to end”.

Comment: @soegaard : but I see there is another layout : https://imgur.com/dtgxdGi

Comment: @soegaard : where the "step->" and "next term" a difference things

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Certain programs will make the macro stepper show these buttons. I am not sure which ones. 

FWIW the new manual is here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/macro-debugger/index.html?q=macro%20debugger#%28part._.Using_the_.Macro_.Stepper%29

Comment: @soegaard : thanks ,I have try to read it once ago，but because not sure what "multiple top-level definitions" is ,so maybe I write a incorrect example.
I wise if someone can tell me.
whatever,it's not a big problem,I can't spend a afternoon on that anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's still a way to get a macro stepper multiple terms using the "Macro Stepper" button in DrRacket, but you can also use [`macro-stepper-repl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/macro-debugger/index.html#(def._((lib._macro-debugger%2Fstepper..rkt)._macro-stepper-repl))) from the `macro-debugger/stepper` library.

Note: in recent versions of Racket (up to and including Racket 7.7), `macro-stepper-repl` will often show "terms" that look like garbage starting with the characters `#~` --- that's how Racket prints "compiled expressions". Those shouldn't be displayed, but there's a bug in the code that tries to filter them out. You can delete those terms from the macro stepper using "Remove selected term" from the "Stepper" menu.